# How to find Reports that are emailed?

Tags: sql-server

We have a lot of daily scheduled SSRS that send out e-mail to a variety of people. One of the destination email recipients has left the company so I need to find all the place that have her e-mail defined.
Can I  write a query in SQl server Studio to search all the scheduled reports for that persons e-mail address?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the report server using the following query:

```
-- List all SSRS subscriptions 
USE [ReportServer];  -- You may change the database name. 
GO 

SELECT USR.UserName AS SubscriptionOwner 
      ,SUB.ModifiedDate 
      ,SUB.[Description] 
      ,SUB.EventType 
      ,SUB.DeliveryExtension 
      ,SUB.LastStatus 
      ,SUB.LastRunTime 
      ,SCH.NextRunTime 
      ,SCH.Name AS ScheduleName       
      ,CAT.[Path] AS ReportPath 
      ,CAT.[Description] AS ReportDescription 
FROM dbo.Subscriptions AS SUB 
     INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS USR 
         ON SUB.OwnerID = USR.UserID 
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Catalog] AS CAT 
         ON SUB.Report_OID = CAT.ItemID 
     INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule AS RS 
         ON SUB.Report_OID = RS.ReportID 
            AND SUB.SubscriptionID = RS.SubscriptionID 
     INNER JOIN dbo.Schedule AS SCH 
         ON RS.ScheduleID = SCH.ScheduleID 
ORDER BY USR.UserName 
        ,CAT.[Path];
```

Credit and more info: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSRS-subscriptions-968ae4d5

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Subscriptions table in the SSRS database, the ExtensionSettings or Description fields could be used.